# Issue with Shadow

Tags: rendering, animation

I often face this issue with shadow.

The Screenshot may be checked for better understanding. In this Screenshot, a character is sitting on a bed, both his hands are resting on bed (it is confirmed in the solid view mode) but his left hand is not casting shadow as it should be.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please provide more information. Is this _Eevee_? I guess so. Then you have to check _Contact Shadows_ on the light sources. If this is not the reason - for eveything else the question is almost unanswerable without more information, or at least just wild speculation.

Comment: If this is EEVEE, as it seems, then please let us know if @GordonBrinkmann 's suggestion, or a touch of AO, help you out.

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: @ Gordon Brinkmann @Robin Betts Thanks for your help. Contact Shadow option works. A Google drive link for the final outcome is placed below for your checking please: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zh-ze9A6FEdjoaZmRXcxrnd1ha78we0r/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why from the image alone. It seems that there are multiple shadow casting lights in the scene as indicated by the back wall and the lack of left casting shadow under the clock by the lamp.  If you're wondering why his left arm and hand aren't casting a shadow on his body, then I suggest turning off all the lights except for the one from the nightstand lamp. Also turn down the global ambient light. Then see if the shadow appears. If it does, then light from your other lights is probably washing out the shadows.

I think you also need to show a render of the left side of his body to verify that there isn't a shadow where the camera can't see in the shot above, because it could just be placement of the arm/hand.